# ORACLE STORED PROCEDURE CURSOR IS WORKING VERY SLOW

Tags: oracle, performance, plsql, cursor

One of my stored procedure recently took around 6 hours which usually takes about 3 hours to complete.
On checking, I found that the cursor is taking the time to execute.

Both the tables are present in my local DB instance.

I need to know what could be the possible reason for this and how the procedure can be fine tuned.

#### My stored procedure:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE VMS_DETAILS_D_1 IS
LOG_D1 VARCHAR2(20);
BEGIN

/* IDENTIFY PARTITION */

SELECT partition_name into LOG_D1 FROM all_tab_partitions a WHERE table_name = 'LOG' AND TABLE_OWNER='OWNER1' and partition_position IN 
(SELECT MAX (partition_position-1) FROM all_tab_partitions b WHERE table_name = a.table_name AND a.table_owner = b.table_owner);

execute immediate 'DROP TABLE TAB1 PURGE';
COMMIT;

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'create table TAB1 Nologging as
select /*+ Parallel(20) */  TRANSACTIONID,TIME_STAMP from OWNER1.log partition('||LOG_D1||') 
where ( MESSAGE = ''WalletUpdate| Request for Estel Update is Processed'' or MESSAGE = ''Voucher Core request processed'')';

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE INDEX IDX_TAB1 on TAB1(TRANSACTIONID)';

DBMS_STATS.GATHER_TABLE_STATS (ownname => 'OWNER2' , tabname => 'TAB1',cascade => true, estimate_percent => 10,method_opt=>'for all indexed columns size 1', granularity => 'ALL', degree => 1);


DECLARE
   CURSOR resp_cur
   IS
        select TRANSACTIONID,to_char(max(TIME_STAMP),'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') TIME_STAMP from TAB1 
        where TRANSACTIONID in (select ORDERREFNUM from TAB2
        where ORDERREFNUM like 'BV%') group by TRANSACTIONID;
BEGIN
   FOR l IN resp_cur
   LOOP
      update TAB2 
      set TCTIME=l.TIME_STAMP 
      where ORDERREFNUM=l.TRANSACTIONID;
      COMMIT;
   END LOOP;
END;

end;
```

---

Comment: this table `OWNER1.log` how much data does contains ?, also its bad modelling to have a condition on column message , maybe some letter will have upper letter or low letter.

Comment: *"I need to know what could be the possible reason for this"* Well what in your system changed between this last run and the previous run (when it apparently ran in an acceptable timeframe)? There's no way we can answer that. Indeed, it may have been a local temporal anomaly, and the next time you run this code it'll be fine.

Comment: Also, how do you know it's the cursor which took the time? Does the procedure have logging code which you have redacted before posting here?

Comment: @moudiz - *"its bad modelling to have a condition on column message"* Is it? Always? Not if the messages are assigned by batch routine from a standard list of messages (say hardcoded in a routine or stored in a table).

Answer (score 2):

First off, DDL has an implicit commit, so you don't need a commit after your drop table.
Secondly, why are you dropping the table and recreating it instead of just truncating the table and inserting into it?
Thirdly, why loop around a cursor to do an update, when you can do it in a single update statement?

If you absolutely must store the data in a separate table, I would rewrite your procedure like so:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE vms_details_d_1 IS
  log_d1 VARCHAR2(20);
BEGIN

  /* IDENTIFY PARTITION */

  SELECT partition_name
  INTO   log_d1
  FROM   all_tab_partitions a
  WHERE  table_name = 'LOG'
  AND    table_owner = 'OWNER1'
  AND    partition_position IN (SELECT MAX(partition_position - 1)
                                FROM   all_tab_partitions b
                                WHERE  table_name = a.table_name
                                AND    a.table_owner = b.table_owner);

  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'TRUNCATE TABLE TAB1 reuse storage';

  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'insert into TAB1 (transactionid, time_stamp)'||CHR(10)||
                    'select /*+ Parallel(20) */  TRANSACTIONID,TIME_STAMP from OWNER1.log partition(' || log_d1 || ')'||CHR(10)||
                    'where MESSAGE in (''WalletUpdate| Request for Estel Update is Processed'', ''Voucher Core request processed'')';

  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE INDEX IDX_TAB1 on TAB1(TRANSACTIONID)';

  dbms_stats.gather_table_stats(ownname          => 'OWNER2',
                                tabname          => 'TAB1',
                                cascade          => TRUE,
                                estimate_percent => 10,
                                method_opt       => 'for all indexed columns size 1',
                                granularity      => 'ALL',
                                degree           => 1);

  MERGE INTO tab2 tgt
    USING (SELECT transactionid,
                  max(time_stamp) ts
           FROM   tab1
           GROUP BY transactionid) src
      ON (tgt.transactionid = src.transactionid)
  WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET tgt.tctime = to_char(src.ts, 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'); -- is tab2.tctime really a string? If it's a date, remove the to_char

  COMMIT;
END vms_details_d_1;
/
```

If you're only copying the data to make it easier to do the update, you don't need to - instead, you can do it all in a single DML statement, like so:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE vms_details_d_1 IS
  log_d1 VARCHAR2(20);
BEGIN

  /* IDENTIFY PARTITION */

  SELECT partition_name
  INTO   log_d1
  FROM   all_tab_partitions a
  WHERE  table_name = 'LOG'
  AND    table_owner = 'OWNER1'
  AND    partition_position IN (SELECT MAX(partition_position - 1)
                                FROM   all_tab_partitions b
                                WHERE  table_name = a.table_name
                                AND    a.table_owner = b.table_owner);

  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'MERGE INTO tab2 tgt'||CHR(10)||
                    '  USING (SELECT transactionid,'||CHR(10)||
                    '                MAX(time_stamp) ts'||CHR(10)||
                    '         FROM   owner1.log partition(' || log_d1 || ')'||CHR(10)||
                    '         GROUP BY transactionid) src'||CHR(10)||
                    '    ON (tgt.transactionid = src.transactionid)'||CHR(10)||
                    'WHEN MATCHED THEN'||CHR(10)||
                    '  UPDATE SET tgt.tctime = to_char(src.ts, ''dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'')'; -- is tab2.tctime really a string? If it's a date, remove the to_char

  COMMIT;
END vms_details_d_1;
/
```

If you know the predicate(s) which define the partition you're after, you can use those in your query, thus removing the need to find the partition name and therefore needing dynamic SQL.

Comment: I think it's a good idea to include the REUSE STORAGE clause when truncating a table. Assuming the volume of data is broadly consistent over each month the saving on extent management is usually worth the risk that sometimes we have allocated space we're not using.

Answer (score 0):

Okay you procedure needs lots of enhancment:

- In the below query you can use `user_tab_partitions`  instead of `all_tab_partitions`.

  SELECT partition_name
      into LOG_D1
      FROM all_tab_partitions a
     WHERE table_name = 'LOG'
       AND TABLE_OWNER = 'OWNER1'
       and partition_position IN
           (SELECT MAX(partition_position - 1)
              FROM all_tab_partitions b
             WHERE table_name = a.table_name
               AND a.table_owner = b.table_owner);
- You have to include a checking on the table tab1 incase if it doesnt exists and no need to commit here, its not a DML statement.

execute immediate 'DROP TABLE TAB1 PURGE';
COMMIT;

- No need to update the statistics in the procedure, especially its a newly table created and the index is already created, and its only one index.

The above might slightly improve the performance but you have to check that there is an index on table log for column message ( but as i said its wrong modeling) also check query plan on tab2 if it needs a index.

Comment: *" you can use `user_tab_partitions`"* Nothing in the question to suggest this operation is run by OWNER1. It's probably OWNER2, or even a third party. Even if it were run by OWNER1 how would this improve performance? *"No need to update the statistics in the procedure*" Disagree totally. Immediately after an initial population is the most important time to gather (or fix) stats.

Comment: @APC as for the 1st point I agree about the different user, however selecting from ALL_ youll go to all the database object with full table scan, even if thers a condition involved. as i said it might slight enhance the performance, as for the second point, please correct my information,1-he created a table, 2)he inserted the data, he created an index on the specific column, so the statistics for this index are up to date, then why he need to update the statistics on the table especially there is no index. [Update statistics after creation of index](https://community.oracle.com/thread/3591765)

Answer (score 0):

This is the wrong approach, what you're doing is update TAB2 the number of times the records in cursor resp_cur, I would switch to a merge.